# How do I create a new list with specific items from an old list in Python 2?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list of lists (I think) that looks like this:

```
[['Cats', 'Dogs', '', 'Gerbils'],
['Tigers', 'Snakes', '', 'Hamsters'],
['Iguanas', 'Snails', '', 'Worms']]
```

I need to build a new list of lists by ignoring the blank fields. So my new lists would look like this:

```
[['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Gerbils'],
['Tigers', 'Snakes', 'Hamsters'],
['Iguanas', 'Snails','Worms']]
```

I've not got a deep understanding of lists in Python so I'm at a complete loss as to how to do this. Can anyone point me to doc that will show me the way?

Thanks!

Edit: list-of-lists syntax corrected by Dan

Comment: First of all, the example is invalid syntax because the elements of the outerlist are not separated by comments. After you fix that I'd use a list comprehension and `filter`. `new_list = [filter(len, inner) for inner in old_list]`

Comment: John Tyree, I think you meant commas rather than comments. But good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
newlist = [ filter(None, x) for x in oldlist ]
```

Edited in response to comments:

It is arguable that using `filter(bool, x)` is more readable than `filter(None, x)`. In effect they are the same, both meaning "filter out the items that are false/None/empty/zero".

In python 3, `filter` returns an iterable object rather than a list, so the equivalent would be

```
newlist = [ list(filter(None, x)) for x in oldlist ]
```

or

```
newlist = [ list(filter(bool, x)) for x in oldlist ]
```

each of which is equivalent to

```
[ [ item for item in x if item ] for x in oldlist ]
```

Comment: FWIW, `filter(bool, x)` is more idiomatic (and exactly the same speed).

Comment: `filter` supports passing `None` as the function argument for exactly this purpose.

Comment: A slightly faster version using `functools.partial`:  `map(partial(filter, None), oldlist)`. But is going to be little slower for such tiny lists.

Comment: [`bool` is specialised in the same place as `None`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/434673580106f4391da2c8937e646be579bc0c4d/Python/bltinmodule.c#L546), which is why it is the same speed. According to [this thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2013-August/022607.html) several people, including core developers think the `None` form should be deprecated.

Comment: @Veedrac: +1. Then again, someone who doesn't care that `filter` already returns an iterator instead of a `list` as of 3.0 probably doesn't care that `filter(None, …)` may be deprecated in some future version beyond 3.4…

Answer (score 4):

```
l = [['Cats', 'Dogs', '', 'Gerbils'],
     ['Tigers', 'Snakes', '', 'Hamsters'],
     ['Iguanas', 'Snails', '', 'Worms']]

[[i for i in sub if i] for sub in l]
```

Output

```
[['Cats', 'Dogs', 'Gerbils'],
 ['Tigers', 'Snakes', 'Hamsters'],
 ['Iguanas', 'Snails', 'Worms']]
```

Comment: And this approach has the advantage that, if the condition winds up being a bit more complicated, the programmer can simply change the `if i` to something else.